# If isset blade laravel is not working laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

i'am new in Laravel and i have the next code:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('erriorIMG','filetype not is supported');
```

in the blade file:

```
@if(isset($erriorIMG))
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        {{ $erriorIMG }}
                    </div>
                @else
                    <h3>sadasd</h3>
                @endif
```

but not working, when i use redirect()->back() i cant pass parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a flash data so try this:

```
Session::get('erriorIMG')
```

reference:

- http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects
- http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session#flash-data

Comment: thanks finally i use:
return \Redirect::back()->withMessage('ERROR');
@if(Session::has('message'))
        {{Session::get('message')}}
    @endif